# Working with nullable

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to minimize if block from below code.Please help me suitable extension method

```
               var v = (from rec in _DataContext.tblCourierMasters
                     where rec.CourierReceievedDate == dtCourierReceivedDate
                           && rec.RegionId == lRegionId
                           && rec.PODNumber == strPODNo
                     select new { rec.TotalCafReceived, rec.ReceiptDoneCount }).FirstOrDefault();

            lTPC = (long)v.TotalCafReceived;
            if (v.ReceiptDoneCount== null) {
                lRDC = -1;
            }
            else
                lRDC = (long)v.ReceiptDoneCount;
```

Comment: that if-else statement doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: I agree 100% with Selman22. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
lDRC = (long)(v.ReceiptDoneCount ?? -1);
```

So if `v.ReceiptDoneCount` is null, `lDRC` will be assigned the value of -1 instead.

Here's a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L3T4iX).

Comment: @EvilMM That is true. OP should check if `v` is null before they proceed further. My answer is based on their if-else statement, however, whose condition was `if (v.ReceiptDoneCount== null)`.